# unordered_map, mapped value changes automatically, Signal 'SIGSEGV' received. Description: Segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, unordered-map

I have been stuck on this for very long time. my codes is large, I try my best to abstract the problematic codes.

I am programming in C++, I use unordered_map to store several variables.

```
class INFO
   {int interestingInfo1;
   double interestingInfo2;}
INFO *info;
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<index,Info*,hashIndex> newMap;

line1:newMap myMap;
line2:myMap[index]=info;
line3:myMap[index]->interestedInfo1;
```

In my program, every object will be accessed multiple times, in the first round of access, the unordered_map works well, I can fetch interested information pointed by `Info`, but when the same object is accessed in the second round, the line 3 code intriguers error of `Segmentation fault`.

I print out the elements in myMap, including `index` and address of the interestedInfo pointed by `Info` (or to say, the value of `Info` itself),

```
index1  0x9765ad8 
...
```

in the second time access, print out the same content:

```
index1 0x98ba128
......
```

The value of pointer `Info` is changed! I guess this change makes line3 crash,

I am now pretty sure that I didn't do anything to `myMap`, but why the pointer as an element is changed?

Please help me! Many thanks!

Comment: Place data break points in strategic point of your code to see who is the culprit which cause to the memory overrun

Comment: @ShmilTheCat thanks for replying, I have set breakpoints, I am sure line 3 is the defendant. I just have no idea how to deal with the strange change of pointer value in the unordered_map.

Comment: Is it just me, or is line 2 suspect? Are you actually passing a string to `insert()`? I think you mean to pass either a `pair` or an initializer list.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña Thanks,there was typo in line2, and I have corrected it.

Comment: @ulyssis2 Figured as much. Just being careful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your custom hashing algorithm may be suspect. I imagine something is causing it to yield different results the different times you access it (maybe you changed something inbetween?) such that when you access it at that key it no longer yields the same value -- or any value, for that matter, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: indices of the elements in newMap are different (they are acutally IPV4Address), the hash function returns the address as an  int. thus I think it is impossible to generate identical value for different key values.